# macOS - UserDefaults is different in Swift and Terminal

Tags: swift, macos, terminal, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to access a system preference (`com.apple.menuextra.clock DateFormat` specifically) from my Swift app using UserDefaults. Using terminal, `defaults read com.apple.menuextra.clock` returns

```
{
    DateFormat = "EEE MMM d  h:mm:ss a";
    FlashDateSeparators = 0;
    IsAnalog = 0;
}
```

However, if I do this in my Swift app

```
print(UserDefaults.standard.dictionary(forKey: "com.apple.menuextra.clock"))
```

I get `nil`.

How do I access this in Swift? If it helps, I'm only looking for `DateFormat` so I know if the user prefers 12- or 24-hour time. I've tried

```
DateFormatter.dateFormat(fromTemplate: "j", options: 0, locale: Locale.current)!
```

then finding whether or not it contains `a`, but that doesn't work either.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To anyone else who has this question in the future: I fixed it by turning off App Sandbox.

Comment: Anyone looking for answer to this question... you will need both UserDefaults.standard.persistentDomain and the sandboxing off

Answer (score 2):

You were not searching in the right domain. When you call `dictionary(forKey:)`, `bool(forKey:)`, `integer(forKey:)`, etc, you are searching through a [hierarchy of domains](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/AboutPreferenceDomains/AboutPreferenceDomains.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i-CH2-SW1):

- [`NSArgumentDomain`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1410665-argumentdomain): the arguments that are passed to your app when it starts.
- Application domain: the keys that you defined in your app.
- [`NSGlobalDomain`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1407355-globaldomain): system-level preferences.
- Languages: system-level preferences that are dictated by the user's choice of language.
- [`NSRegistrationDomain`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1415953-registrationdomain): temporary keys that your app define. Must be re-registered every time your app launches. If you want it to stick, use the Application Domain.

`com.apple.menuextra.clock` is not a key in the hierarchy above. It's a domain by itself (think of it as a separate app with its own preferences). Use this instead:

```
if let dict = UserDefaults.standard.persistentDomain(forName: "com.apple.menuextra.clock") {
    print(dict)
}
```

Comment: `UserDefaults.standard.persistentDomain(forName: "com.apple.menuextra.clock")` still returns nil.

Comment: Anyone looking for answer to this question... you will need both UserDefaults.standard.persistentDomain and the sandboxing off